# Можно ли отключить автоматическую установку обновлений на Win11 Home?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-11

Win11, не 10. home, а не pro. Возможно ли отключение автообновлений помимо блокировки адресов скачивания?

Comment: Можно. В службах отключи

Comment: @eri разумеется, все советы в интернетах в виде отключения сервиса, груповых политик и регедита не работают, иначе бы не задавал вопрос. Именно на этой версии винды

Comment: @Александр зарегистрируйте полноценный аккаунт, зайдите в профиль и завершите регистрацию, далее ознакомьтесь со статьёй справки: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Александр все отключается.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью встроенными средствами Windows отключить нельзя, только на время поставить паузу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]